# Vertically center link on screen in HTML

Tags: html, css, center

This is the HTML code I have:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Start</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
    <a href="start.html" id="start-button">Start</a>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is my CSS:

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

div#wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;

    background-color: black;

    overflow: hidden;
}

a#start-button {
    /* How to center? *?
}
```

My question is: How can I center the link vertically? I don't want to give the page a fixed height. I tried some options, but they were all not really working or not exacty my problem. 
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go

**OPTION - 1**

**[WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/nnevq/)**

**The HTML:**

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <a href="start.html" id="start-button">Start</a>
</div>
```

**The CSS:**

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

div#wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;

    background-color: black;

    overflow: hidden;
}

a#start-button {
    display: list-item;
    list-style: none outside none;
    text-align: center;
}
```

**The CSS Code Change:**

```
a#start-button {
    display: list-item;
    list-style: none outside none;
    text-align: center;
}
```

**OPTION - 2**

**[WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/nnevq/1/)**

**The HTML:**

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <a href="start.html" id="start-button">Start</a>
</div>
```

**The CSS:**

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

div#wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display:table;

    background-color: black;

    overflow: hidden;
}

a#start-button {
    display: table-cell;
    text-align:center;
}
```

**The Code Change:**

```
div#wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display:table;

    background-color: black;

    overflow: hidden;
}

    a#start-button {
        display: table-cell;
        text-align:center;
    }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Did you saw both of my options?? Do both dont work or either of them?? - @DennisvB

Answer (score 1):

**[See the Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Kek7c/1/)**

You need to give the parent `div` `display: table` and child `display : table-cell` with `vertical-align: middle`

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
div#wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: black;
    overflow: auto;
    display: table;
}

a#start-button {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: add text-align center also to a.. I was trying to do same but didn't apply table-cell to a +1 for your ans....

Answer (score 0):

Try using display:table-cell on the containing div.  Then you can apply a vertical-align:middle to it.

Comment: `vertical-align:middle `

Comment: Thanks, I see what you mean in the other answers.